# Django rest api does not save password

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework, model

I want to make a user registration form. Everything works and the user is saved, but his password is not stored. When I see the user page in admin it is in the password field -> **"Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."**. i use default user mode.

this is my code ->

serializers.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User(
                username=validated_data['username']
            )
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

views.py

```
class CreateUser(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny]
    serializer_class=RegisterSerializer
    

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return Response({
        "user": RegisterSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data, 
        "token": token.key
        })
```

Comment: Are you sure the user with the invalid password was created with this code? `User.set_password` should take care of the hashing properly. The recommended way of creating users is to use `UserManager.create_user()` method. Maybe you could try that instead in the serializer create method.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#topics-auth-creating-users

Comment: @HåkenLid Does not work anyway

Comment: What is the raw value in the password field? Should look something like this `pbkdf2_sha256$216000$th2Eu3RfC8pf$cySuS1Qrda0BareeIUZv1bnq6/UcgbJ0m0SrRcxu/iU=`. The last part is the hash, and the parts separated by `$` tells django which hashing algorithm that was used to set the password.

Comment: @HåkenLid Nothing at all. Do not need a confirm password?

Comment: If you have called `user.set_password(plaintext_password)` there should be a hashed value stored in the password field. You can't see it in the admin interface. Use python or database shell to access the raw content.

Comment: @HåkenLid I saw it and it is not

Comment: The message `"Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."` would happen if you had set the password using `user.password = plaintext_pw` instead of `user.set_password(plaintext_pw)`. That's not what happens in your serializer. So it seems there must be some other way the invalid password was set.

Comment: @HåkenLid When I open the API page in chrome, the password field does not contain snowflakes. The text is written in the input. it's correct?

Comment: Yes. The api html form is meant for development and debugging, so password input is  a regular CharField with a text type input widget by default. You should not use the html form of the api as a user facing interface.

Comment: @HåkenLid Oops. The password is stored in the database as text and not as a hash. I saw it in sql viewer